# Reaquiring chametz

Tags: halacha, halacha-theory, passover

Mishna Berura on Shulchan Aruch Siman 434 Seif 2

> מיד בלילה יבטלנו - הטעם הוא דאע"ג דמדאורייתא בבדיקה לבד סגי דמן התורה
> סגי באחד מהן או בביעור או בביטול דאפילו אם ישאר שם חמץ בבית אינו עובר
> עליו כ"ז שלא נודע לו כיון שבדק היטב ועשה כל מה שמוטל עליו מ"מ חכמים
> חששו שמא ימצא גלוסקא יפה שאינה נבטלת מעצמה כמו פירורין וישהה מעט קודם
> שישרפנו ויעבור עליו בבל יראה אבל אם יבטלנו שוב אינו עובר בכל גווני בבל
> יראה דהוי הפקר ולאו דיליה הוא:

In summary the M"B is saying that although from Torah law, either bitul chametz or bedikat chametz would be sufficient, the Sages required both, as even if one were to do only a thorough bedika, he may later find a desirable piece of chametz during the holiday and delay burning it and by this violate the Torah prohibition of בל יראה.

It seems that the issue here is that when he waits and does not immediately burn it, he is contemplating keeping it, which makes him liable as he momentarily *continues* to keep his chametz.

However, if he did bitul beforehand, rendering the chametz like hefker, isn't there the same concern of him thinking of keeping it? If the chametz doesn't belong to anyone, can't he aquire it at that moment?

Comment: What act of kinyan would he be performing that would allow acquisition? Especially considering that the chametz is assur behana'ah.

Comment: If he does not do *bitul* and there was lost *chametz* in his house then he is not *oyver* till he finds the *chametz* because the *chametz* was not *nimtza* (so he is not *oyver* on *lo yimatze*). Even if pauses in its destruction after finding then he is *oyver* because now it is *nimtza*. If he does *bitul* and pauses then he is not *oyver* because it is not his. The *chashash* is that he will pause, not that he will reacquire the *chametz*, because if so then he could acquire any *chametz*.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Are there situations where it truly is possible to acquire chametz? It would seem that it's forbidden to purchase chametz in a store, but why is that different from deciding to keep a piece of ownerless chametz (assuming that is how batel chametz is considered)?

Comment: Bitul  before Pesach does not work if now he does desire it.